# Undefined namespace windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I write this for chat app in WP7, and I need to put it on project

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

                xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:Chat.Controls">
```

and I get this error

```
Error   7   Undefined CLR namespace. The 'clr-namespace' URI refers to a namespace 'Chat.Controls' that is not included in the assembly.    C:\Users\Amin\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Chat\Chat\WP7_Chat\Control.xaml 4   36  Chat
```

Need I to add an assembly or what??

Comment: Do you have the namespace Chat.Controls in the assembly?

Comment: So, you just answered your own question ;) If the namespace is not declared in the assembly, of course it will be undefined.

Comment: ok, I try to declare it but I don't found it in the assembly

Comment: Are you copying that code from somewhere and trying to use it in your xaml?

Answer (score 1):

Doing `xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:Chat.Controls"` means that you're using a namespace local to the current assembly (in the same project as that piece of XAML), but the compiler says that it doesn't exist.

So either you have the wrong namespace, or you're missing the assembly after the namespace (something like `xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:Chat.Controls;assembly=Chat.Controls"`

Comment: yeah, its local, but how can I add it?